# jQuery dynamic table calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

I have made a dynamic form/table and i can't calculate new added rows correctly.

All is fine for static part, but when I add a new row the ID's and classes of a row don't match the function...new added rows are not calculated at all.
can someone help please?

```
<div>
<h2>Offer</h2>
<form>
<table id="t1">
  <tr>
    <th><button type="button" class="addRow">Add</button></th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price per hour</th>
    <th>Hours</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><select name="personal"><optgroup label="Personal"><option value="k&ouml;che">K&ouml;che</option><option value="barkeeper">Barkeeper</option><option value="garderobiere">Garderobiere</option><option value="chauffeure">Chauffeure</option><option value="oberkellner">Oberkellner</option><option value="serviceleitung">Serviceleitung</option><option value="hilfskoch">Hilfskoch</option><option value="servicekr&auml;fte">Servicekr&auml;fte</option></optgroup></select></td>
    <td><input name="anzahl" class="amount" value="" /></td>
    <td><input name="preisps" class="amount" value="" /></td>
    <td><input name="stunden" class="amount" value="" /></td>
    <td><input name="total" class="total" id="total1" value="" readonly="readonly" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br />

<table id="t2">
  <tr>
    <td>Netto =<br></td>
    <td><input id="netto" readonly="readonly" name="netto" type="text" value=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Steuer 19% =<br></td>
    <td><input id="steuer" readonly="readonly" name="steuer" type="text" value=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Brutto =<br></td>
    <td><input id="brutto" readonly="readonly" name="brutto" type="text" value=""></td>
  </tr>
</table>
    <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <input type="reset" value="Reset">
  </form>
</div>


<script>  
// main function when page is opened
$(document).ready(function () {

      // function for adding a new row
      var r=1;
      $('.addRow').click(function(){  
          r++;  
          $('#t1').append('<tr id="row'+r+'"><td><select name="personal"><optgroup label="Personal"><option value="k&ouml;che">K&ouml;che</option><option value="barkeeper">Barkeeper</option><option value="garderobiere">Garderobiere</option><option value="chauffeure">Chauffeure</option><option value="oberkellner">Oberkellner</option><option value="serviceleitung">Serviceleitung</option><option value="hilfskoch">Hilfskoch</option><option value="servicekr&auml;fte">Servicekr&auml;fte</option></optgroup></select></td><td><input class="amount" value="" /></td><td><input class="amount" value="" /></td><td><input class="amount" value="" /></td><td><input class="total" value="" readonly="readonly" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+r+'" class="btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
      });
      // remove row when X is clicked     
      $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
           var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
           $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
      });
      // calculate everything
      $(document).on("keyup", ".amount", calcAll);      
});


// function for calculating everything
function calcAll() {
      // calculate total for one row
      var product = 1;
      $(".amount").each(function () {
            if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
            product *= parseFloat(this.value);
            }
            $("#total1").val(product.toFixed(2));
      });

      // sum all totals
      var sum = 0;
      $(".total").each(function () {
          if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
              sum += parseFloat(this.value);
          }
      });
      // show values in netto, steuer, brutto fields
      $("#netto").val(sum.toFixed(2));
      $("#steuer").val(sum.toFixed(2) * 0.19);
      $("#brutto").val(parseFloat(sum.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(($("#steuer").val())));
}
</script>
```

here is my source code:

http://jsfiddle.net/p2Hbm/86/

Comment: where is the problem exactly? I've added numbers and rows and it seems to work fine

Comment: try to add a new row (click on button Add) and then write the values for the new row. It doesn't work as it should. It writes everything in the last column of the first row. :(

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p2Hbm/97/   This is the last version and it works now...big thanks to @M.K. Wierzba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made an example on how you can do this on jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/gtcazp7s/

```
    // main function when page is opened
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // function for adding a new row
        var r = 1;
        $('.addRow').click(function () {
            r++;
            $('#t1').append('<tr id="row' + r + '" class="item"><td><select name="personal"><optgroup label="Personal"><option value="k&ouml;che">K&ouml;che</option><option value="barkeeper">Barkeeper</option><option value="garderobiere">Garderobiere</option><option value="chauffeure">Chauffeure</option><option value="oberkellner">Oberkellner</option><option value="serviceleitung">Serviceleitung</option><option value="hilfskoch">Hilfskoch</option><option value="servicekr&auml;fte">Servicekr&auml;fte</option></optgroup></select></td><td><input class="qnty amount" value="" /></td><td><input class="price amount" value="" /></td><td><input class="hours amount" value="" /></td><td><input class="total" value="" readonly="readonly" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + r + '" class="btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
        });
        // remove row when X is clicked
        $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function () {
            var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
            $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
        });
        // calculate everything
        $(document).on("keyup", ".amount", calcAll);
        //$(".amount").on("change", calcAll);
    });

    // function for calculating everything
    function calcAll() {
        // calculate total for one row

        $(".item").each(function () {
            var qnty = 1;
            var price = 1;
            var hours = 1;
            var total = 1;
            if (!isNaN(parseFloat($(this).find(".qnty").val()))) {
                qnty = parseFloat($(this).find(".qnty").val());
            }
            if (!isNaN(parseFloat($(this).find(".price").val()))) {
                price = parseFloat($(this).find(".price").val());
            }
            if (!isNaN(parseFloat($(this).find(".hours").val()))) {
                hours = parseFloat($(this).find(".hours").val());
            }
            total = qnty * price * hours;
            $(this).find(".total").val(total.toFixed(2));
        });

        //$(".amount").each(function () {

        //    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
        //        product *= parseFloat(this.value);
        //    }
        //    $("#total1").val(product.toFixed(2));
        //    if (!isNaN($(this).find(".qnty"))) {

        //    }
        //});

        // sum all totals
        var sum = 0;
        $(".total").each(function () {
            if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }
        });
        // show values in netto, steuer, brutto fields
        // show values in netto, steuer, brutto fields
        $("#netto").val(sum.toFixed(2));
        $("#steuer").val(parseFloat(sum * 0.19).toFixed(2));
        $("#brutto").val(parseFloat(sum.toFixed(2) + parseFloat(($("#steuer").val()))).toFixed(2));
    }
```

Here's the html part:

```
<div>
    <h2>Offer</h2>
    <form>
        <table id="t1">
            <tr>
                <th><button type="button" class="addRow">Add</button></th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Price per hour</th>
                <th>Hours</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="item">
                <td><select name="personal"><optgroup label="Personal"><option value="k&ouml;che">K&ouml;che</option><option value="barkeeper">Barkeeper</option><option value="garderobiere">Garderobiere</option><option value="chauffeure">Chauffeure</option><option value="oberkellner">Oberkellner</option><option value="serviceleitung">Serviceleitung</option><option value="hilfskoch">Hilfskoch</option><option value="servicekr&auml;fte">Servicekr&auml;fte</option></optgroup></select></td>
                <td><input name="anzahl" class="qnty amount" value="" /></td>
                <td><input name="preisps" class="price amount" value="" /></td>
                <td><input name="stunden" class="hours amount" value="" /></td>
                <td><input name="total" class="total" id="total1" value="" readonly="readonly" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <br />

        <table id="t2">
            <tr>
                <td>Netto =<br></td>
                <td><input id="netto" readonly="readonly" name="netto" type="text" value=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Steuer 19% =<br></td>
                <td><input id="steuer" readonly="readonly" name="steuer" type="text" value=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brutto =<br></td>
                <td><input id="brutto" readonly="readonly" name="brutto" type="text" value=""></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This is working perfectly.....i have learned a lot now! Thank you! This can be used for anything....just need to change the labels and it works...here is the final version, i just deleted old code: http://jsfiddle.net/p2Hbm/90/

Comment: There is just one more thing.....hmm if a row is added before you typeany values then when you start typing the numbers are not rounded to 2 decimal places....i don't know where to change that

Comment: can you provide a screenshot? I've edit a js part of the post try it.

Comment: :( now when i write 22 22 22 in fields in brutto field i get  12671.119999999999??? and if i only write 33 in first field also i get more than 2 decimal places

Comment: try this:
 $("#brutto").val(parseFloat(sum.toFixed(2) + parseFloat(($("#steuer").val()))).toFixed(2));

Comment: It concatenates them instead of adding them :( i'm really sorry if i am taking your time! You have already helped enough!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109908/discussion-between-lewis4u-and-m-k-wierzba).